# Prevent APIs using PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have end-points like below:

```
app.post(api + '/channels/:channel_id/albums', user.ensureAuthenticated, album.create);
app.get(api + '/channels/:channel_id/albums/published', user.ensureAuthenticated,album.publishedAlbums);
app.get(api + '/channels/:channel_id/albums', user.ensureAuthenticated, album.findAll);
```

It all works fine, but it's annoying for me to put user.ensureAuthenticated in each of the end-points, are there any method that you can once put the user.ensureAuthentication at once for all?

For ex: Laravel has such options like beforeAuth you make an if and inside that u put all the end-points that you want to make protected.

like for ex:

```
if(user.ensureAuthenticated){
  // endpoints declariations
}else{
  // redirect to login
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find an answer here : 
[Only allow passportjs authenticated users to visit protected page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756848/only-allow-passportjs-authenticated-users-to-visit-protected-page)

Especially this kind of code :

```
//checks to be sure users are authenticated
app.all("*", function(req, res, next){
if (!req.user) 
    res.send(403);
else
    next();
});
```

All endpoints will be secured.

Comment: After this code without the user.ensureAuthenticated parameter.

Comment: What if my routes are not in one single file?

Comment: No problem, just put the app.all route before all your code.

Comment: That's the problem actually :), bc I dont want those other routes to be protected as some of them should be public.

Comment: May you use a whitelist system on a subset of routes using a function like in this sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650489/express-js-sessions-activated-on-a-subset-of-routes